# how do I use wildcards in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I have seen lots of questions sort of like this, but not exactly.

In my robots.txt I want to do something like:

Disallow: `/home/[anything]/[anything]/personal/`

yet allow access to `/home`, `home/xxx`, `/home/xxx/yyy/`, etc

where `*` can be any intervening directory.  The example above is what I've tried and lots of variations on this, nothing seems to work.

`*/personal`

`/home*/personal`

just about every permutation.

Can this be done with the limited wildcards in robots?  If so -- how?

There's lots of info out there on robots.txt, and a lot of it conflicting!]

Comment: robots.txt doesn't allow or disallow access, it is simply a set of rules you would *like* robots to follow based on their user-agent strings or other criteria.  For access control, you want to use something like .htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [robots.txt : how to disallow subfolders of dynamic folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068876/robots-txt-how-to-disallow-subfolders-of-dynamic-folder)

Comment: Understood.  I guess I wasn't clear enough that search robots are what I'm targeting.

Answer (score 1):

The Google crawler understands patterns within `robots.txt`, but keep in mind **not all bots do** (or will even follow robots.txt at all for that matter).  For example:

```
Disallow: /*foo.html$
```

Would disallow any `foo.html` document.

Check out the [Robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) for more information.  They also have a [test tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?rd=1) to verify if your rules are working correctly.

Comment: So, in my case I should try: */statistics$  for example?  Thanks.

Comment: Yea sounds right.  Use the test tool as well to verify things are working correctly, and keep in mind it probably won't block every search engine.

Comment: Understood.  I'm just worried about the big one!

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster Tools has a great tool for trying out robots.txt directives (at least as Google Bot will interpret them). You can add a line into the robots file right inside webmaster tools, and add a url you want to make sure gets blocked, hit the test button and it will tell you if it's blocked or allowed and if blocked, which directive (line number) did it. See attached screenshot. (ah booo to stackoverflow - it won't allow me to add the screenshot, cause I don't have any 'reputations').